# Speccy and SpeedFan not showing cpu fan speed

Tags: laptop, cpu, fan, cooling, temperature

I have a HP dv3 notebook. I have just downloaded speccy. Altough there is written that speccy has the property that can show fan speed,

[image]

my copy (v1.26.698) does not have even this line ever. When compare the screenshot on the internet this line(fan speed) seems does not exist on my copy.

For example, I found a screenshot on the internet:
[image]

And this line gone on my copy:
[image]

After all when I look at SpeedFan, interestingly it does not show fan speed also:
[image]

Is it all about my notebook model or I really does not have any fan in my notebook although high fan volume?

Is there any other software that works much more properly?

Comment: This type of support is very hardware specific.  My guess your hardware doesn't have the capability of reporting the RPM of the fan.

Comment: Did you try [HWMonitor](http://www.cpuid.com/softwares/hwmonitor.html)?

Comment: @and31415 I just tried HWMonitor. It didn't show. I think my hardware doesn't have the capability of reporting the RPM of the fan as Ramhound said

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some deeper search I understand that it is related to report capablity of my CPU

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: @Raystafarian It seems there is no solution for this issue. So answer is: no solution.